# Posting Complex JSON Data in .NET Core WebAPI Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I need to read json data which is posted by client pay load to my API is something like below:

```json
{
   "result": {
      "destinationId":"003",
      "message":"msg",
      "sourceEntityId":"1",
      "status":"0"
   }
}
```

My `HttpPost` code is something like below:

```cs
public ActionResult Post([FromBody] clsTicketinfo ticketInfo)
{
   // Some Code
}
```

Please help me to read this json data in my `HttpPost` method. Also how to read the headers data which is sent by client along with post request.

Comment: Can you posr t clsTicketInfo class too.

Comment: public class clsTicketInfo
    {
    
        string affectedCIs;
        string affectedLocations;
        string assignedToGroup;
     // lot of other fields with property defined
    }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post JSON data to Dotnet Core webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51991835/post-json-data-to-dotnet-core-webapi)

Comment: No, I think so because I want to read the data which is sent via post by the client along with headers

Comment: You actually want to read raw JSON? Why?

Comment: because it has some information like message i need to read it

Answer (score 0):

Your `clsTicketinfo` class should look like this

```cs
public class clsTicketInfo 
{ 
    public Result result { get; set;} // <- add this line
    public string affectedCIs {get; set;}
    public string affectedLocations {get; set;}; 
    public string assignedToGroup {get; set;}; 
    // lot of other fields with property defined 
}
```

And you should create another class with the name `Result` or whatever you want, as below:

```cs
public class Result
{
    public string destinationId { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string sourceEntityId { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```